# Why does chaning my serve method break my index.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I recently changed my express code from

```
// correctly located index.html
app.use('/', express.static(root_path));
```

to

```
// correctly locates index.html
// but index.html paths are broken
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(cud, '..', 'index.html'));
});
```

Please note that index.html is correctly served in both cases.  However the code in index.html has the paths broken.

```
  // loads a script using the DOM and an optional argument to bust the cache
  function loadScript(path, bust) {
    console.log("Loading | " + path + " | " + bust)
    const ref = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[ 0 ];
    const bundle = document.createElement( 'script' );
    if(bust){
      path = path + '?cache_buster=' + bust;
    }
    bundle.src = path;
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore( bundle, ref );
  }

  loadScript('dist/bundle.js');
```

Comment: When you say `index.html` paths are broken, do you mean other resources loaded from within `index.html`?  If so, that's because you no longer have any route for those resources.  Express, by itself, serves no files at all.  Your `express.static()` line that you removed was serving a whole directory hierarchy of static files, but apparently you removed that.

Comment: Oh.... well how do I setup a path to serve bundle.js?

Comment: Or can I use both `sendFile()` and `static()`? What caused this refactor, is I need access `req.user` on my initial page load and I can't do this using just the static folder or can I?

Comment: Just put the `app.get("/", ...)` `sendFile()` route BEFORE the `express.static()` route and you can have both.  Routes are matched in the order defined so the "/" route will match first and it will serve up `index.html`.  All the other routes that aren't "/" will get handled by the `express.static()` route.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `express.static` to serve any files in your `public` directory.

```
app.use(express.static('path/to/public/folder'))
```

You should continue to use `app.get('/'...` This is the correct method.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'index.html'))
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

Comment: according to the comment by jfriend above sendFile() should be used before static().  Do you comply?

Comment: That only applies when declaring a specific route with `app.use()`.. in your case you are just wanting the static assets to be available from a public folder